# Connecting to a mysql database from a separate Application

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, openshift

First time using OpenShift, and I've read that I am able to connect to a database on a different application under my account.

I have APPLICATION A that is a Ruby/MySQL project.
I have APPLICATION B that is a PHP project.

I'd like to connect to my APPLICATION A MySQL database from my APPLICATION B PHP script. When doing an `rhc apps` command, I can see that my connection URL reads:

`Connection URL: mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQLDB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQLDB_PORT`

When looking at my environment variables on my APPLICATION A server, I see they are:

```
OPENSHIFT_MYSQLDB_PORT=3306
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_HOST=127.7.171.129
```

But when I try to connect:

```
$db = new mysqli('127.7.171.129', 'adminuser', 'adminpw', 'productiondb',3306);
```

And I dump out this:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (17) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  NULL
  ["client_info"]=>
  NULL
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50169)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(2005)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  string(57) "Unknown MySQL server host 'http://127.7.171.129' (1)"
  ["errno"]=>
  NULL
  ["error"]=>
  NULL
  ["field_count"]=>
  NULL
  ["host_info"]=>
  NULL
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["server_info"]=>
  NULL
  ["server_version"]=>
  NULL
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  NULL
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  NULL
  ["thread_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["warning_count"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: `http://127.7.171.129` is invalid

Comment: That was a mistype. I do not use http://. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a KB article that has a couple of suggestions:  https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1051-how-do-i-connect-multiple-applications-to-one-database

Can you take a look to see if it helps?